# How to draw this finite automaton?

Tags: automata

I have to draw this automaton ( can be deterministic or not) where L is the language on the alphabet {a,b}
and where the words that starts with an a have an even length ( ex: aabbab) and the words that starts by a b have an odd length (ex: baa).

This is what i tried, could someone tell me if i am correct. It seems ok to me. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks for reply, but it said in the question that the automaton can be non-deterministic, so this would work right ? Thanks.

Comment: yes, makes sense, sorry overlooked

Comment: Your machine is not correct: it accepts $aa$, and it also accepts $b$. But a different 4-state machine will work.

Comment: @BrianO: It’s supposed to accept $aa$ and $b$.

Comment: It works, but it’s more complicated than necessary: you can simply delete state $4$ and the transitions associated with it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oops yes I had the polarity reversed, my bad.

Comment: @BrianO oh you're right state 4 is useless, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @codetime You mean to thank BrianM.Scott :)

Comment: What is the status of the empty word? Should it be accepted or not?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin that's a good question, i am a bit confused with this one since, if it's empty there's an even number of letters but it doesn't start with an a tho ?

Comment: Basically, it just means that your definition of $L$ is incomplete. You have to say whether $L$ contains the empty word or not separately.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin That's the only info i have : words that start by a "a" have an even length of letters and words that starts by a "b" have an odd length. My opinion is that they cannot be empty because the language says the words that start by a b or a, if they are empty it doesn't start by any of those. What do you think ? Thanks.